# pg_autofailover setup with password

Tags: postgresql, load-balancing, high-availability, citus

I have created the postgres with pg_auto failover on one primary and one secondary node .
I am followed this link. https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2019/05/30/introducing-pg-auto-failover/ I tested the failover and Replication without --auth tag on monitor and postgres node. It works fine without any authurization.
Here are the commands

```
    export PATH="$PATH:/usr/pgsql-11/bin"
    pg_autoctl create monitor --nodename 10.247.74.66 --pgport 6000
    export PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/node_a
    pg_autoctl create postgres --nodename 10.247.74.66 --pgport 6001 --dbname test --monitor postgres://autoctl_node@10.247.74.66:6000/pg_auto_failover
    pg_autoctl run
```

2nd node

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/pgsql-11/bin"
export PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/node_b
pg_autoctl create postgres --nodename 10.247.74.67 --pgport 6002 --dbname test --monitor postgres://autoctl_node@10.247.74.66:6000/pg_auto_failover
pg_autoctl run

pg_autoctl show state


        Name |   Port | Group |  Node |     Current State |    Assigned State
-------------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------+------------------
10.247.74.66 |   6001 |     0 |     1 |           primary |           primary
10.247.74.67 |   6002 |     0 |     2 |         secondary |         secondary
```

I added the autherization on monitor node as --auth md5 and altered the password of autoctl_node of pg_auto_failover database following this link https://pg-auto-failover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html Monitor node also works fine. But when I added --auth md5 in primary node_a and node_b , nodes are stucked in waiting and catching up.

```
    export PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/monitor
    pg_autoctl create monitor --auth md5 --nodename 10.247.74.66 --pgport 6000
    export PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/node_a
    pg_autoctl create postgres --auth md5 --nodename 10.247.74.66 --pgport 6001 --dbname test --monitor postgres://autoctl_node:BMGAAES123z3RZ5ZSwq@10.247.74.66:6000/pg_auto_failover
    pg_autoctl config set replication.password ZUp3aEAy123BEmTb44A
    pg_autoctl run

    export PGPASSWORD=ZUp3aEAy123BEmTb44A
    export PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/node_b
    pg_autoctl create postgres --auth md5 --nodename 10.247.74.67 --pgport 6002 --dbname test --monitor postgres://autoctl_node:BMGAAES123z3RZ5ZSwq@10.247.74.66:6000/pg_auto_failover
    pg_autoctl config set replication.password ZUp3aEAy123BEmTb44A
    pg_autoctl run

        Name |   Port | Group |  Node |     Current State |    Assigned State
-------------+--------+-------+-------+-------------------+------------------
10.247.74.66 |   6001 |     0 |     1 |      wait_primary |      wait_primary
10.247.74.67 |   6002 |     0 |     2 |        catchingup |        catchingup
```

Logs of primary node_a

```
2021-04-02 19:06:32.028 IST [19588] LOG:  connection received: host=10.247.74.66 port=52598
2021-04-02 19:06:32.031 IST [19588] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgautofailover_monitor"
2021-04-02 19:06:32.031 IST [19588] DETAIL:  User "pgautofailover_monitor" has no password assigned.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all "pgautofailover_monitor" 10.247.74.66/32 md5 # Auto-generated by pg_auto_failover"
2021-04-02 19:06:34.034 IST [19609] LOG:  connection received: host=10.247.74.66 port=52618
2021-04-02 19:06:34.036 IST [19609] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgautofailover_monitor"
2021-04-02 19:06:34.036 IST [19609] DETAIL:  User "pgautofailover_monitor" has no password assigned.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all "pgautofailover_monitor" 10.247.74.66/32 md5 # Auto-generated by pg_auto_failover"
2021-04-02 19:06:36.041 IST [19626] LOG:  connection received: host=10.247.74.66 port=52628
2021-04-02 19:06:36.043 IST [19626] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgautofailover_monitor"
2021-04-02 19:06:36.043 IST [19626] DETAIL:  User "pgautofailover_monitor" has no password assigned.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all "pgautofailover_monitor" 10.247.74.66/32 md5 # Auto-generated by pg_auto_failover"
```

Logs of Secondary node_b

```
2021-04-02 19:08:32.099 IST [8755] LOG:  connection received: host=10.247.74.66 port=41682
2021-04-02 19:08:32.101 IST [8755] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgautofailover_monitor"
2021-04-02 19:08:32.101 IST [8755] DETAIL:  User "pgautofailover_monitor" has no password assigned.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all "pgautofailover_monitor" 10.247.74.66/32 md5 # Auto-generated by pg_auto_failover"
2021-04-02 19:08:34.105 IST [8758] LOG:  connection received: host=10.247.74.66 port=41732
2021-04-02 19:08:34.107 IST [8758] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgautofailover_monitor"
2021-04-02 19:08:34.107 IST [8758] DETAIL:  User "pgautofailover_monitor" has no password assigned.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all "pgautofailover_monitor" 10.247.74.66/32 md5 # Auto-generated by pg_auto_failover"
2021-04-02 19:08:36.111 IST [8760] LOG:  connection received: host=10.247.74.66 port=41762
2021-04-02 19:08:36.115 IST [8760] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pgautofailover_monitor"
2021-04-02 19:08:36.115 IST [8760] DETAIL:  User "pgautofailover_monitor" has no password assigned.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all "pgautofailover_monitor" 10.247.74.66/32 md5 # Auto-generated by pg_auto_failover"
```

Answer (score 1):

(Already replied via slack channel but let me copy & paste my answer)

`pg_autoctl` only changes the password that it uses to connect to postgres.
That means, you need to make sure that you configured both the HBA file and the password settings in postgres side.
(Related issue on github https://github.com/citusdata/pg_auto_failover/issues/382)